# target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(pro.getProperty(""))).click();

for(String newWindow : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
}

driver.close();

Log.info("Closing the current Opened Window - Invoice");
driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow); ---error in this line
```

I am getting error while switching to main window.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target
>   window already closed from unknown error: web view not found

I have tried switching to default window, commenting driver.close and adding thread.sleep also but issue not resolved.

Comment: Are you sure there was another window? what is the size of `driver.getWindowHandles()`?

Answer (score 0):

@user7309686 Hope the below script will solve your problem. better to put one validation before switch to new windows. Thanks

```
public  void switchToNewWindow(WebDriver driver)
{
    String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> openedWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    if(openedWindows.size() > 1)
    {
        for(String newWindow : openedWindows)
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
        }
        driver.close();
        Log.info("Closing the current Opened Window - Invoice");
        driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
    }
}
```

Comment: issue not resolved .i think it is not issue with code. when i use same code in(selenium) my system it works. but this issue only occurs in cloud remote server.I changed chromedriver and all jars but still not working. please help

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar case in `python`. The issue was that selenium wasn't able to keep track of opening a new window if you are closing a window just before.

The solution is to add this line
`driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])`, which tells selenium to visit the last tab (before opening the new window).

```py
for i, labelResultUrl in enumerate(labelResultUrls):
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])  #this line will fix
    driver.switch_to.new_window()
    driver.get(labelResultUrl)

    ...

    if failCount == 0:
        driver.close()

    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me in C#, I don't know Java though:

```
foreach (var tab in driver.WindowHandles)
{
driver.SwitchTo().Window(tab);
}
```